# How much information of the length of a plaintext can an adversary get from its ciphertext?

Tags: public-key, provable-security

Let $\Pi$ be a public-key encryption scheme. For every palintext $x \in \{0,1\}^{*}$, is there a PPT adversary $A$ such that
$$\Pr \left[ 1^{|x|} \leftarrow A\left( pk, \mathrm{Enc}_{pk} (x) \right) \right] \geq 1 / poly \left( \lambda \right)$$
or even
$$\Pr \left[ 1^{|x|} \leftarrow A\left( pk, \mathrm{Enc}_{pk} (x) \right) \right] \geq 1 - \varepsilon\left( \lambda \right)$$

Of course, if the plaintext space is finite (e.g. $\mathcal{P} = \{0,1\}^{m}$), it is not true.
Here we assume that $\mathcal{P} = \{0,1\}^{*}$.

The definitions of many kinds of security (e.g. IND-CPA) have a condition that the test plaintexts must have the same length.
Maybe, it implies that the ciphertext must preserve some information about the length of the plaintext. Is there a formal form about it?

Comment: By definition, you can say that the ciphertext $\operatorname{len}(C) \geq \operatorname{len}(P)$, so some information about the plaintext size is always known (assuming that $\operatorname{Enc}$ doesn't manage to compress the plaintext $P$).

Comment: The practical reason for the equal-length restriction in security definitions is to break schemes that are (except for some constant overhead) length-preserving, e.g. AES-GCM with a non-repeating nonce is CPA secure under standard definitions but if you allow variable length inputs, you can trivially distinguish a 1-byte from a 2-byte message.